# Find If a curve formed by the Normal vector and curvature of a another curve is contained in a plane

Tags: differential-geometry

So I have this curve $$ \alpha(t) = (t−sin(t), 1−cos(t), 4 sin( \frac{t}{2}))$$
which is not parametrized by arclength.
And I need to find if the curve $$\gamma(t) = \alpha(t) + k_{\alpha}(t) N_{\alpha}(t) $$ is contained on a plane.
I've been trying to solve this problem by finding the curvature and normal vector of $\alpha$.
However it's getting too complicated and I don't know if there is an easier and better way to approach this.

Thanks in advance.